# When a NavigationController push to a TabBarController , Why after the first tab bar item , TableViewController's contentInset is wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitabbarcontroller

My TabBarItems is `UITableViewController`.

When I from a NavigationController push in a `TabBarController`, 
After the first items, `tableView.contentInset` is `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)`

But sometimes, when I set the `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 0, 0)`. The `tableView.contentInset` it became to `UIEdgeInsetsMake(128, 0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: By the way , I'm using storyboard , How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncheck Adjust Scroll View Insets in View Controller Attributes, or `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO` if not using storyboard. This was introduced in iOS 7, so you might do a version check if needed.

Comment: Yes , I'm try to use it , but it's can't fix my question

Comment: By the way , I'm using storyboard , How can I solve it ?